# block type="core/template" template="template.phtml" for specific category

Tags: category, category-products, cms-block

I'm using a cms block as  homepage's new products.

In this block I can choose from which category it show me products ( from all categories, only from category n°1, only from category n°2 ecc. )

I want to use this block also into the category n°1 and I want to display here only products from this category.. How can I do this?

Comment: If My answer help you then mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Go to catalog->category->select your category -> custom design

and in `Custom Layout Update` please write below code

```
<reference name="content">
   <block type="core/template"  template="template.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Comment: I have small doubt, is my block type right : {{block type="core/template" template="top_selling_items_list/top_selling.php"}}  my top_selling.php available at app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/top_selling_items_list/top_selling

Answer (score 1):

As you shown, `block type=“core/template” template=“template.phtml”`,
you can pass **category_id** as a parameter, like : `block type=“core/template” template=“template.phtml” category_id="52"`.

Now you can access this **category_id** in `template.phtml`, like `$this->getCategoryId()`, and can filter products with this **category_id**.

By the way, you can use/pass as many parameters as you want.

Answer (score 0):

{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Where the column_count value is the number of columns.

Navigate to System->Permissions->Blocks.

Click on the Add new block button.

Specify your Block Name, which is: catalog/product_list.

And allow the Block using the YES/No Dropdown list: